# UISearchBar disappears on cancel

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

My app is iPad landscape, using autolayout.

The initial view has a table view that occupies only half of the screen (the other half is a MapKit view).

This view controller containing that table (and the map view) is the top view controller of the app's root navigation controller.

On view load, I instantiate the `UISearchController` and add its search bar to the table view's header view, as is standard procedure.

If I tap the search bar and enter some text, results are displayed. If I cancel the search here, no problem.

If instead, I select one of the result rows, and push into the next screen, and pop back, the search bar is gone. I can restore it by calling again:

self.tableView.headerView = self.searchController.searchBar

in viewDidAppear(), but that only works until I tap the search bar's 'cancel' button (at which point, it disappears again - **right after the scope button collapse animation ends**).

I have seen very many similar questions, but none describes my exact symptoms, and none of the solutions (or anything else I could think of):

```
// In viewDidLoad():

self.definesPresentationContext = true

self.searchController.definesPresentationContext = true

self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

self.navigationController?.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

...seem to work in my case.

The weirdest part is, I have other similar table views with search interfaces (presented in modal view controllers), with no difference I can spot with respect to configuration, and those work alright...

I know I must be missing something...

Comment: I'm not sure but I saw a something similarly when made the own controllers. Try to play with the `presentationContext`.

Comment: You mean `definesPresentationContex`? I've tried `true` and `false`. False causes the search bar to remain on screen even after navigating to the next view controller (push segue).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Exactly this issue I saw in my controllers. Can you check `navigationBar.translucent` value after returning from a child controller? Maybe child controller is set a value `navigationBar.translucent` to the `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of trying everything, I found the offending code:

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    // Dismiss the keyboard
    self.resultSearchController.resignFirstResponder()

    // Reload of table data
    self.resultSearchController.loadView()
}
```

After commenting these two lines out -or better, the whole method (since I'm not doing anything else in it)- the problem sorted itself out.

NOTE: One of my coworkers implemented that method while trying different things to get the search to work as expected, and it somehow stuck...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. Sometimes, when Cancel button is tapped, the search bar is disappeared too. What I found is that if the search bar is reset to table header again, this could cause search bar disappeared. Therefore I have the following updated codes to resolve the issue.

```
func setupSearchController(_ ctr: UISearchController?)  {
  if let sc = car { // search bar is not nil
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
      navigationItem.searchController = sc
    } else {
      // Fallback on earlier versions
      if tableView.tableHeaderView == nil {
        tableView.tableHeaderView = sc.searchBar
      }
    }
  } else {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
      navigationItem.searchController = nil
    } else {
      // Fallback on earlier versions
      tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
    }
  }
}
```

Note: for iOS 11 or above, the search bar is set to navigation item.